# Vue.js trying to call an template which don't exist

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently new to Vue.js and front end developper.
I'm following Vue.js introduction.
Here's my index. html.
There's no code to show about app.js given I erase everything.

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello World !
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</html>
```

However when I use a http-server to display my page there's one error.
And then it's ONLY when I refresh the page that I note that the error is:

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app-5
```

Does anyone can explain me why it cannot find app5 ? index.html doesn't have any

```
<div id="#app-5">
```

and my app.js is empty so how is it possible that the browser is still looking for app-5 ?

Thanks

Comment: If `app.js` really is empty, delete the `<script>` tag that references `app.js` and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Thank you it work. However it seem that my modification aren't taking in account. When I write code with error syntax, the browser warns me about my syntax error. Then once I correct it, the browser keep warns me about the same syntax error. So when I erase the whole code in app.js, then browser keep warning me about error syntax even when the code doesn't exist anymore ! I have definitively any idea about what's going on ... help ?

Comment: Sounds like something is being cached.  Empty your cache and re-try or use CTRL+F5 to refresh instead of F5.

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript doesn't update after a refresh, in addition to a force refresh [mentioned by Patrick Steele](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921428/vue-js-trying-to-call-an-template-which-dont-exist/49924963#comment86863860_49921428), you can disable the cache when the developer tools window is opened.

In Chrome:

[image]

In Firefox

[image]